# SpringBoot: Timeout when the endpoint doesn't return a response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and looking for a way to Timeout when endpoint takes more than 3 seconds to return the response. I tried by adding the property "server.servlet.session.timeout", but still no luck. How to achieve this? Thanks.

```
@GetMapping("/api")
public Data getData(){

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    return ....;
}
```

Application.properties

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=3s
```

Comment: no, "*servlet.session*" is not good for "request" ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your http client looks like. (RestTemplate/WebClient). But using WebClient this is how you can create TimeOut for your need.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
  .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000);
```

Refer this for a detailed explanation:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-timeout